# PyInstaller error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.__init__._version'

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, statsmodels

I am attempting to build an exe file that utilizes statsmodels via PyInstaller, from the terminal. The exe file is built by PyInstaller without error--however when run I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.__init__._version'
```

I have tried installing the statsmodels hook in the PyInstaller "hooks" directory, as described [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2183), however that does not work. I have also attempted to explicitly import statsmodels.**init**._version in my Python code, but that has also not worked. Below is the top of my code where I import the packages:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors, KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import stats
from sklearn import datasets, neighbors
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
import seaborn as sns
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import sklearn.utils._cython_blas
import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs
import statsmodels.tsa.statespace._filters
import statsmodels.tsa.statespace._filters._conventional
import statsmodels.tsa.statespace._filters._univariate
import statsmodels.tsa.statespace._filters._univariate_diffuse
import statsmodels.tsa.statespace._filters._inversions
import statsmodels.tsa.statespace._smoothers
import statsmodels.tsa.statespace._smoothers._conventional
import statsmodels.tsa.statespace._smoothers._univariate
import statsmodels.tsa.statespace._smoothers._univariate_diffuse
import statsmodels.tsa.statespace._smoothers._classical
import statsmodels.tsa.statespace._smoothers._alternative
import statsmodels.__init__._version
```

Here is the traceback of the error:

```
File "LR.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "statsmodels/api.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "statsmodels/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.__init__._version'
```

What can I do to fix this so that the exe file includes the statsmodels package and can be run?

Comment: It should be `import statsmodels._version` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`statsmodels` version is accessed through the `__version__` attribute.

```
import statsmodels

print(statsmodels.__version__)
```

which shows

```
v0.12.0rc0+20.g98dfc0073
```

on my system.

You should replace `import statsmodels.__init__._version` with `from statsmodels.__init__ import __version__`

Comment: So, is this a fix?

Comment: So how can this be implemented to fix my problem?

Comment: @arhodes4 - don't do `import statsmodels.__init__._version` - 
Instead do `import statsmodels` and when you need the version number use `statsmodels.__version__`